# How can I avoid resolving a service when not needed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a Razor page that uses a service for a maintenance job that runs once a week, like this:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IndexModel(IMyService service)
    {
        myService = service;
    }

    private IMyService myService;;

    public void OnGet()
    {
        if (DateTime.Now - LastCheck > TimeSpan.FromDays(7))
        {
            IMyService useService = myService; // Use the service
        }
    }
}
```

However, as I have understood, the service is resolved on each request, even though it's only needed once a week.

This costs time and memory.

Is there a way to only resolve the service when it is used?

How can

Comment: "This costs time and memory." How much time and memory does this cost? Can you measure this and describe the impact it has on your application?

Comment: @Steven, I haven't measured anything, but I run on a shared host with limited memory pr site, so I want to use as little as possible.

Comment: But if you haven't measured anything, how would you know whether this is a problem? Typically. the creation of services [should be really fast](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) and the amount of memory they hold would only be a few bytes. What's different in your case that could cause problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to register it as a `Func<MyService>` so that you can lazy instantiate e.g. registration:

```
services.AddSingleton<Func<MyService>>(_ => () =>
    return (DateTime.Now > TimeSpan.FromDays(7)) ? new MyService() : null);
```

then

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IndexModel(Func<MyService> func)
    {
        myService = func.Invoke();
    }

    private IMyService myService;

    public void OnGet()
    {
        myService?.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Another option could be to register it as a singleton e.g.

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
```

Comment: As I understand this code, the actual service will turn into a `Transient` service, a new instance created each time the `Func` condition returns true, is that correctly understood?

Comment: hmm not quite. The code registers a `Func<MyService>` singleton, which injected into IndexModel. A MyService instance is evaluated in the ctor, but returns null if your predicate condition (in the registration) is not met. This means you're not *always* creating/allocating instances of MyService objects in memory. Note: you could also invoke the Func inside the `OnGet` method to make even more lazy... you still have the cost of the Func<MyService> injected to IndexModel, but this is registered as a singleton (at least in my example).

Answer (score 0):

you can register it as singleton, then it will be just one item of it

the resolving is not important (it won't create a new one every time , it would just gets it form some sort of dictionary)

take a look at this Microsoft article  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: A singleton still resolves the service even if it is not needed - the server is recycled every day so there's still a waste.